# How to extend JPA entity to just add composition

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, composition

I have a concrete class for Employee entity.  Employee is persisted by other application, I'm just using the data.  I want to extend Employee to add properties that are other Entities using composition.  I don't need to persist a child entity per se, but only the entities I'm trying to extend to Employee with using composition.  Here is some code to help clear things up.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Legacy_Table_Name", schema = "another_owner")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "emp_id")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String emp_id;
    private String firstName;
    etc...
```

-

```
public class EnhancedEmployee extends Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Transient
    private SomeEntity someCompositionProperty;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<AnotherEntityWithItsOwnTable1> list1;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<AnotherEntityWithItsOwnTable2> list2;
```

If I make `EnhancedEmployee` an entity then JPA tries to create/use an `EnhancedEmployee` database table (right now in dev so I'm using create-drop persistence.xml property).  If I remove the @Entity annotation from EnhancedEmployee, JPA complains that EnhancedEmployee is not an Entity in other classes where I want to utilize these extra properties

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinTable(name = "PARTICIPATING_EMPLOYEES", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "event_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id") })
private Collection<EnhancedEmployee > participants;
```

All I'm trying to do is reference an Employee setter getters for these extra properties whether or not they have data persisted for these extra properties.

I realize I could probably just modify my Employee class and add someCompositionProperty and list1/2 relations to that class but doesn't that then violate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle.  While my Employee entity class is the "same" for all my projects the source code is really part of each project's package so perhaps the open/closed doesn't apply here and I should just modify the Employee entity class

Answer (score 2):

> If I make EnhancedEmployee an entity then JPA tries to create/use an
> EnhancedEmployee database table (right now in dev so I'm using
> create-drop persistence.xml property).

You could avoid this by changing the inheritance type to [`SINGLE_TABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/InheritanceType.html#SINGLE_TABLE)

Also your discriminator column `emp_id` seems to me like a bad choice. Better change it to something like `@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")` because emp_id is the primary key and and cannot repeat itself in a table. Also your EnhancedEmployee needs `@DiscriminatorValue(value = "ENHANCED")`

Comment: hmm it might be this simple! I'll have to run through this tomorrow, getting Repeated column in mapping for entity...

Comment: So the Repeated column in mapping for entity error is because I need to use the PK of the superclass "emp_id" as the discriminator.  Even putting insertable/updateable false gives me the error. If I remove @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "emp_id") entity manager expects a DType field.